# Django Templateform issue with multiple databases

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to using multiple databases in my Django project.

As you can see I am trying to use the `custom` database rather than `default`. In the other functions where the data is correctly extracted from the database mentioned in `objects.using='database'.

Only while trying to save the form data using a django Templateform the `default` database is considered and I am getting the error as below:

```
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such table: base_clientprofile
Exception Location: /opt/.../.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py in execute, line 485
```

Below is my config and code samples.

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        },
        'trace_one': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'somename',
            'USER': 'rootuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
        }
    }

DATABASES_ROUTERS = ['DefaultRouter', 'TraceProdRouter']
```

**forms.py**

```
class TraceClientProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ClientProfile
        fields = [
            'full_name',
            'short_name',
            'address',
            ]
```

**views.py**

```
def trace_post_model_client_create_view(request):
    form = TraceClientProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.save(using='trace_one')
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/traceviews/{num}".format(num=obj.id))
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    template = "trace_tmpl/trace_client_create_view.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^create/$', trace_post_model_client_create_view, name='traceclientcreate'),

)
```

**routers.py**

```
class MasterRouter(object):
    def __init__(self, app_label):
        super(MasterRouter, self).__init__()
        self.app_label = app_label

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return self.app_label
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return self.app_label
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == self.app_label or obj2._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'default':
            return model._meta.app_label == self.app_label
        elif model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return False
        return None


class DefaultRouter(MasterRouter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DefaultRouter, self).__init__('default')


class TraceProdRouter(MasterRouter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TraceProdRouter, self).__init__('trace_one')
```

Comment: I can't see any reference to a custom database here. You pass `using='default'` to the save method.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. My bad, I have changed from obj.save(using='default') to obj.save(using='trace_one'). But it doesn't work in either case.

Comment: Do the tables exist in `trace_one` database? Have you configured your [database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) ?

Comment: Have added routers.py and updated settings.py with DATABASE_ROUTERS config.